# strange transform of dirac delta function

Tags: fourier-analysis, dirac-delta

one of our homework solutions states that $$\delta(x)\equiv\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega e^{-i\omega x} $$ is the Fourier transform of the dirac delta function. But according to the definition $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d\omega \delta(\omega)e^{-i\omega x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ must be the fourier transform. So what does that identity above mean and how was it derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess:

The statement in your homework solution is **not** giving you the Fourier transform of the dirac delta function.  What it **is** saying is that we can define the dirac delta function as the inverse Fourier transform of $f(\omega) = 1$.  That is, we can define
$$
\delta(x) \equiv \frac 1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d \omega \, 1 \cdot e^{i \omega x}
$$
Note that it is much more typical to have the transforms be functions of $\omega$ than functions of $x$, hence my suspicions.

Comment: Is there a Minus missing in the Exponent?

Comment: Not in the usual definition.  Do you have minus there that shouldn't be there?

Comment: In my homework solution there is one $-i\omega x$

Comment: That's strange... either way, it may be a valid definition of $\delta(x)$.  It's clear they're defining $\delta(x)$ and *not* its Fourier transform.

Comment: The two common sign conventions come from different communities.  Most physicists and mathematicians use +i for the forward transform, many engineers use -j.  This is completely rationalized by letting j = -i.  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4604354/7882 is a decent overview over how much hassle this can cause.  (I would also argue that the conjugate variable should be f rather than ω, or equivalently that a factor of 2pi needs to go in the integral.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform is defined differently between some authors: sometimes is defined as $X(i\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$ (symmetric way, preferred by mathematicians), sometimes as $X(i\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$ (preferred by electrical engineers, where commonly they use $j = \sqrt{-1}$ instead of "$i$"), and there are also its alternatives using the standard frequency "$f$" instead of the angular frequency "$\omega$", and also sometimes there differences on sign of the complex exponential kernel. This is why in the Wikipedia page of the Fourier transform [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tables_of_important_Fourier_transforms)], on the tables of functions vs they transforms are columns with different alternatives.

Both alternatives leads to $x(t)=\mathbb{F}^{-1}\{\mathbb{F}\{x(t)\}\}$, but if you compare $X(i\omega)$ between alternatives, you will find a difference of a factor of $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

You have to be aware of this when using software like Wolfram-Alpha [[2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform+calculator)], since its solutions could be delivered by a different definition from the one you have mind.